# how to solve problem error occurs when open setting page or cotacts page in odoo 16 localhost

Tags: python, localhost, odoo, odoo-16

when i open setting page or Contacts page, an error occurs

UncaughtPromiseError > TypeError

وعد لم يتم رصده > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')
at web/assets/1771-d8153f9/web.assets_backend.min.js:6521:211
at traverse (web/assets/1771-d8153f9/web.assets_backend.min.js:6516:200)
at web/assets/1771-d8153f9/web.assets_backend.min.js:6516:242
at Function.each (web/assets/1759-a4a3557/web.assets_common.min.js:171:149)
at traverse (http://localhost:8056/web/assets/1771-d8153f9/web.assets_backend.min.js:6516:211)
at http://localhost:8056/web/assets/1771-d8153f9/web.assets_backend.min.js:6516:242
at Function.each (http://localhost:8056/web/assets/1759-a4a3557/web.assets_common.min.js:171:149)
at traverse (http://localhost:8056/web/assets/1771-d8153f9/web.assets_backend.min.js:6516:211)
at http://localhost:8056/web/assets/1771-d8153f9/web.assets_backend.min.js:6516:242
at Function.each (http://localhost:8056/web/assets/1759-a4a3557/web.assets_common.min.js:171:149)
```

i need to solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read about how to provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [edit] to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the feature "Regenerate Assets Bundles" via the developer tools.

Often times this solves those kind of issues. If it is not enough, please provide more informations about what you did before this error happened and I will help you further!